# SharePoint online anonymous contact form

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, anonymous-authentication, azure-functions

We have E5 Office 365 subscription. Now we have requirement that we have to put anonymous page where public will add data and that data should go to SharePoint Online custom list.

We have Azure account too. Please suggest me or give us some article.

Comment: Any help will be appriciate

Answer (score 2):

For anonymous access you can use a dedicated SP Site Collection or a Forms form.

A form in Forms would be the neat way. People would type the data in the form and a Flow could be triggered to write the data in to SharePoint. Thus you isolate the input area from the working area and work on high security level.
A SharePoint Site Collection would need a lot more editing show only the allowed content of the anonymous users.

The explanation for the form settings can be found [**here**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/adjust-your-form-or-quiz-settings-in-microsoft-forms-f255a4ba-e03c-4e12-b880-f7e8b62e0665)

Here is a [**response**](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/I-want-Flow-to-use-a-FORM-that-when-submitted-will-update-fields/m-p/87694/highlight/true#M8653) from MS Power Users Board, where the Flow workflow is pictured and explained.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this within MS products is by using Microsoft Flow. See the links from Christian for an explanation.

There's no option to give anonymous access to SharePoint site collections. This has been deprecated and disabled for a while now. See https://support.office.com/en-us/article/external-sharing-overview-c8a462eb-0723-4b0b-8d0a-70feafe4be85 for an overview of the things you can share anonymously.

---

If you are using Azure Functions to talk to SharePoint this blog post might be helpful: https://bob1german.com/2017/06/24/az-func-simplestart/

It show how you can use the CSOM api's to talk to SharePoint.

Comment: I found the way, you can do with OAuth method. I am working on it and it is working as expected. I am nearly 90% done. Once done I will add that solution as answer

Comment: Using oauth is not anonymous... I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Yes, it is not purely anonymous. But end user don't have to login to the SharePoint Online and we can retrieve data and add data through REST API

Comment: I'm wondering how you're doing this and if you have full grasp of the security implications. Be sure that you are not sharing some kind of admin credentials (or client id and secret) somewhere. I see you are using Azure Functions so that might be secure enough.

Comment: Btw the Forms approach is a very good no-code solution.

Comment: Well do you have any article, which shows step by step.

Comment: This link from Christian's post should be a solution https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/I-want-Flow-to-use-a-FORM-that-when-submitted-will-update-fields/m-p/87694#M8653